# What distribution has CDF $\propto \psi ^{(1)}\left(x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)$

Tags: random-variable, moment-generating-function, distribution-identification

Is there a way to express random variable with the following CDF $g(x)$, $x\ge 0$, in terms of known named distributions? $$g(x)\propto \psi ^{(1)}\left(x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$ where $\psi^{(k)}$ is the [polygamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) function.

This distribution [arises](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286847/217) when sampling numbers $1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16},\ldots$ with relative frequencies $1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16},\ldots$

Comment: Well, if $X$ takes the values $1,\frac14,\frac19,...$ with probability proportional to $1,\frac14,\frac19,...$, then the distribution of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}}$ is clearly zeta(2). Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @Glen_b ah I see, that's a good point. I guess then I'm looking for a continuous random variable whose CDF matches the CDF of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}}$ at non-differentiable points

Comment: The polygamma function you use appears to be constant, so can be removed from the proportionality statement.  Can you please modify your post to correctly state the proportionality requirement and the *support* of interest.

Comment: Domain is positive $x$, here's a [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5BPolyGamma%5B1%2C+1%2FSqrt%5Bx%5D%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+2%7D%5D). Another name for the function is [Trigamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function)